# How do I replace the HDD in a ASUS Q550L?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, laptop-repair

I just bought a ASUS Q550L for my son for Christmas and before I open it up I want to be sure I can replace the HDD with an SSD.

Is this model compatible with standard laptop SSDs? If so how do I replace the existing HDD?

Comment: For reference, I have had dealings with ASUS (in 2012): They are a good quality brand but would not provide any links to service manuals or information on how to perform even the simplest maintenance. Good luck.

Comment: don't you mean asus Q550LF?

Answer (score 3):

All you have to worry about is the interface, the actual type of the drive is irrelevant. As long as they support the same plug in the back of the drive, it should be fine (though the OS will need to load new drivers).

As for physically replacing it, you’ll have to check the manual, and if you are not comfortable doing it, then you’ll want to have someone who is do it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally any laptop has 1 or two panels on bottom that are easily removed after unfastening a screw or two. The harddrive is usually one and the ram is the other.
The drive will come right out just make sure you slide it toward whatever open area is available before tilting it or you risk damaging the interface. Generally there's a plastic pull tab.
If there's no obviously removable panels on bottom check along the sides. It may be mounted kinda like a cd drive with it's back end exposed to the edge.
Barring those two possibilities I'd recommend not opening it but if you feel confident and want to try it will be held together with little tabs along the edge seams all the way around the base. Start just off the corners with a small knife or tab tool. Once you get a couple it should come pretty easy.

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with the typical method employed by Dell, HP, etc, but this Asus machine only has one full bottom panel and I can't seem to locate a service manual for it. I was just hoping someone had experience with this particular unit and could guide me on how safe it was to take the bottom panel off. It has eight screws around the perimeter of the bottom.

Comment: Then check the manual.

Answer (score 0):

> before I open it up I want to be sure I can replace the HDD with an SSD.

Yes you can.

You remove the eight screws around the perimeter, separate the bottom single access panel from the main body.

This laptop will have a SATA hard drive so you can replace the old HDD with the new SSD.

ASUS is not very well documented on this piece of equipment swap and instead directs the user to an "Authorized ASUS tech" and to be sure to use "Approved Hard drives"...

You noted in a comment "Wanting to know how safe it is". If you are asking and not feeling confident, do not risk the task yourself, follow ASUS recommendation to seek a qualified tech.

Comment: Carl B; Thanks for the info. I have a great deal of experience with Dell & HP Laptops which provide excellent service manuals. For the new Asus, I just didn't know if their were hidden screws and latches under the keyboard or blind tabs that I didn't want to break accidentally. But if all it is is the eight screws you mentioned that I have already located, I should be fine, although I sure would appreciate a service manual. Mike